# Dynamic ImageButton method crashes android with smartface 4.4

Tags: smartface.io

The dynamic imagebuttons created by smartface 4.4 version crash on android when button clicked without any error during execution of code. The same code works proper with smartface 4.3 Some bug with 4.4?

```
var myImgBtn = new SMF.UI.ImageButton({
    width : '50%',
    height : '50%',
    left : '10%',
    top : '10%',
    image : 'Default.png',
    text : "Click Me!"
});
```

Pages.Page1.add(myImgBtn);

Answer (score 0):

It is already fixed.
New version of Smartface(450) will be released today.

Whe it is released, you can download it from account page: https://account.smartface.io/Account/Register/